# Argument "*main::4" isn't numeric in rand

Tags: perl

With this script

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $w = rand * 4;
```

the interpreter gives me this warning: `Argument "*main::4" isn't numeric in rand`. I don't understand why this is and would like someone to explain what's happening here.

Of course, I can make the warning disappear with `rand() * 4` or `4 * rand`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In perl, `*` is the sigil for a weird type called a typeglob. A typeglob is the symbol table entry for all objects identified by that name - for example, if you were to run:

```
$a = 1;
*b = *a;
print $b;
```

You would get `1`. There are some other things you can do with typeglobs, but none of them are terribly useful or relevant.

The Perl parser is working left to right. It sees that you are attempting to assign the value of `rand * 4` to `my $w`. It identifies `rand` as the name of a built-in function, and starts looking for an argument. Then, it sees a `*`, and interprets it as a sigil rather than an operator. It successfully identifies the argument (`*4`) which is syntactically a legal identifier, and as far as the interpreter is concerned, it's finished parsing that line. It isn't until we actually call the built-in `rand` that the interpreter figures out that a typeglob isn't a legal argument.

So, this happens because:

- Perl checks to see if `rand` has a legal argument first, and if it doesn't, it calls it with no argument
- In Perl, `*4` is the legal name of a variable
- Perl does not have strict types on arguments, so the lexer can't recognize that `rand` doesn't want to have a typeglob passed in to it

You can fix this by:

- Reordering the arguments `4 * rand`
- Explicitly calling `rand()` with no arguments

Comment: `rand(4);` will probably have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Perl was interpreting `*4` as argument to `rand()`, and to be more precise as `*main::4` which is globtype to package variable.

```
perl -we 'my $w = rand (*::4);'
```

same output:

```
Argument "*main::4" isn't numeric in rand
```

Deparse has same idea about these equivalents,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e 'my $w = rand *4;'
my $w = rand *4;
```

---

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e 'my $w = rand *main::4;'
my $w = rand *4;
```